# problem in SDM with Maxent algorithm: Error in .local(object, ...) : Error in prediction

Tags: maxent

Good afternoon everyone,

I am modeling the spatial distribution of a species of spider, when using the SDM function and setting "maxent" as the method, the error appears:

Error in .local(object, ...) : Error in prediction....!

But if I change to the "bioclim" algorithm the error does not appear, not what does that error mean, really in the command I only change from maxent to bioclim and the error no longer appears, could someone help me with that?

Thank you
​

I tried running all the commands again and it doesn't work, if I put the bioclim method it doesn't give an error, but if I change it to maxent the error appears